# При перезагрузки пк, издаётся звук как будто сильно и резко выдувается воздух . Из-за чего это?

Tags: железо, пк

При перезагрузки пк, издаётся звук как будто сильно и резко выдувается воздух . Из-за чего это?

Answer (score 1):

Так и есть, "сильно и резко выдувается воздух". Все вентиляторы включаются на полную мощность. Потом их производительность начинает регулироваться в соответствии с температурой. Возможно, это сделано намеренно, чтобы выдуть пыль.